# lazy find/search for commands within emacs

Tags: commands, help, help-mode

Is there a way to do a lazy find/search within EMACS, for commands using their description?

Something in the lines of:

- Say I am looking for how to add indent to org mode
- I suspect there is a commands for it
- I would like to type "org" and "indent" in any order and get some options/help buffer, based on the documentation as well as the actual commands.

In other words, I would like for emacs to suggest options/help, based on my description/keywords

This would come in handy, how can I do this?

P.S

I am a NOOB!

Comment: Maybe `apropos-command` is what you're looking for. It's bound to `C-h a` by default.

Comment: Personally, I use `helm-info-elisp`, but I don't think there's a single answer for this one.

Answer (score 7):

One way you can try to find such commands is to use **`C-h a`**.  In vanilla Emacs this is bound to `apropos-command`.

For **`C-h a`** you can input words to match in the command documentation - e.g., `org` and `indent`.

```
C-h a org indent
```

This is the kind of output you get:

```
Type RET on an entry to view its full documentation.

org-indent-line (750)         M-x ... RET
   Indent line depending on context.
org-indent-mode (680)         M-x ... RET
   When active, indent text according to outline structure.
org-return-indent (671)       M-x ... RET
   Goto next table row or insert a newline and indent.
org-indent-region (654)       M-x ... RET
   Indent each non-blank line in the region.
org-unindent-buffer (647)     M-x ... RET
   Un-indent the visible part of the buffer.
org-indent-item (582)         M-x ... RET
   Indent a local list item, but not its children.
org-indent-block (579)        M-x ... RET
   Indent the block at point.
org-indent-drawer (573)       M-x ... RET
   Indent the drawer at point.
org-delete-indentation (567)  M-x ... RET
   Join current line to previous and fix whitespace at join.
org-indent-item-tree (564)    M-x ... RET
   Indent a local list item including its children.
org-indent-to-column (564)    M-x ... RET
   Indent from point with tabs and spaces until COLUMN is reached.
org-cdlatex-environment-indent (490)  M-x ... RET
   Execute `cdlatex-environment' and indent the inserted environment.
```

**However**, your question asks how to match against command descriptions, not just command names.  `C-h a` cannot help with that - it matches only against command names.

---

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can *match against command descriptions*, i.e., doc strings.

There are several [Icicles apropos commands](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos), which can help.

You can see information about commands and other things by matching patterns incrementally: change your current minibuffer input and the set of matches changes accordingly.

In this case, you don't have a good idea about the command name, and you want to find a command whose *doc string matches one or more patterns* (e.g. regexps) - e.g., two simple patterns: `org` and `indent`.

[Multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) **`icicle-fundoc`** prompts you for a 2-part, [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) input.

- The first part is a pattern that matches the **name** of a function
- The second part is a pattern that matches its **documentation**.

If you use **`C-$`** during completion it toggles between all functions and just commands (interactive functions).

To match both `org` and `indent` *in either order*, you can use [progressive completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).

You use **`C-M-j`** to separate the parts of your input.

Summary:

1. `M-x icicle-fundoc`
2. `C-$` - match only commands.
3. At the prompt:

   - `.*` - you don't know what the command names are (or use `org.*` if you know the name contains `org`, or use `^org.*` if you it starts with `org`)
   - `C-M-j`
   - `.*[iI]ndent` - match `indent` or `Indent` in the doc
   - `S-SPC` - to provide another pattern
   - `.*org` - and match `org`

In my Emacs that shows these 12 completion candidates:

> ```
> org-cdlatex-environment-indent
> Execute ‘cdlatex-environment’ and indent the inserted environment.
>
> ENVIRONMENT and ITEM are passed to ‘cdlatex-environment’.
>
> The inserted environment is indented to current indentation
> unless point is at the beginning of the line, in which the
> environment remains unintended.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-block
> Indent the block at point.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-drawer
> Indent the drawer at point.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-item
> Indent a local list item, but not its children.
> If a region is active, all items inside will be moved.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-item-tree
> Indent a local list item including its children.
> If a region is active, all items inside will be moved.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-line
> Indent line depending on context.
>
> Indentation is done according to the following rules:
>
>  - Footnote definitions, diary sexps, headlines and inline tasks
>    have to start at column 0.
>
>  - On the very first line of an element, consider, in order, the
>    next rules until one matches:
>
>    1. If there’s a sibling element before, ignoring footnote
>       definitions and inline tasks, indent like its first line.
>
>    2. If element has a parent, indent like its contents.  More
>       precisely, if parent is an item, indent after the
>       description part, if any, or the bullet (see
>       ‘org-list-description-max-indent’).  Else, indent like
>       parent’s first line.
>
>    3. Otherwise, indent relatively to current level, if
>       ‘org-adapt-indentation’ is non-nil, or to left margin.
>
>  - On a blank line at the end of an element, indent according to
>    the type of the element.  More precisely
>
>    1. If element is a plain list, an item, or a footnote
>       definition, indent like the very last element within.
>
>    2. If element is a paragraph, indent like its last non blank
>       line.
>
>    3. Otherwise, indent like its very first line.
>
>  - In the code part of a source block, use language major mode
>    to indent current line if ‘org-src-tab-acts-natively’ is
>    non-nil.  If it is nil, do nothing.
>
>  - Otherwise, indent like the first non-blank line above.
>
>  The function doesn’t indent an item as it could break the whole
>  list structure.  Instead, use ‘<M-S-left>’ or ‘<M-S-right>’.
>
>  Also align node properties according to ‘org-property-format’.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-indent-mode
> When active, indent text according to outline structure.
>
> Internally this works by adding ‘line-prefix’ and ‘wrap-prefix’
> properties, after each buffer modification, on the modified zone.
>
> The process is synchronous.  Though, initial indentation of
> buffer, which can take a few seconds on large buffers, is done
> during idle time.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-list-repair
> Fix indentation, bullets and checkboxes in the list at point.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-return-indent
> Goto next table row or insert a newline and indent.
> Calls ‘org-table-next-row’ or ‘newline-and-indent’, depending on
> context.  See the individual commands for more information.
> ```

---

> ```
> org-unindent-buffer
> Un-indent the visible part of the buffer.
> Relative indentation (between items, inside blocks, etc.) isn’t
> modified.
> ```

---

You can continue to use `S-SPC` to enter other patterns to match, to narrow the list of candidates.

---

- Why did `C-h a` list also command `org-delete-indentation`, but it is missing from the list of Icicles candidates? Because we didn't try to match `indent` also in the command name, and *`indent` is missing from that doc string*.
- Why is command `org-list-repair` included among the Icicles candidates but missing from the output of `C-h a`? Because it contains `indent` *only in the doc string*, not in the command name.  *`C-h a` does not match against doc.*

With Icicles you can match anything in the command name or the doc string, or both. *With `apropos-command` you can match only against the command name.*

Comment: It feels like what you are saying might be the one I want. All I need to do is `M-x package-install` `icicles` and I should be ready to go after that right? I am noob, sorry.  Also from what you said, it appears that I have to toggle between the different results, I don't get to see everything in a buffer, right?

Comment: [Download the files from EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries#BulkIciclesDownload) (the files on MELPA are out-of-date). Put the files in a directory in your `load-path`. Add `(require 'icicles)` to your init file. Turn on Icicle mode (e.g., `(icy-mode 1)` in your init file, or use `M-x icy-mode`).

Dunno what you mean by toggle between the results. The results are matches for your minibuffer input. You can choose one, to see it in buffer `*Help*`, or you can just hit `C-g` to cancel. `icicle-fundoc` is a help command - it shows you function+doc matching your input.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to that might be `<M-x describe-bindings>` which is generally mapped to `<C-h b>`. Then you can switch to that window `<C-x o>` and search `<C-s>` for the bindings available in whatever modes you have set for the given buffer.

In addition, the way I've been learning comes from the way Spacemacs does it.  I'm no longer actually using Spacemacs but it bundles a package called which-key: https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key which will do exactly what you described which is provide a keybind and a brief description.  So if you key `<C-x>` for example, it will put up a window with all the possible following combinations with a brief description of what it will do.  I'm still using it in my current configuration and find it very helpful.

Comment: I am afraid maybe what I am saying is not clear. I want to type keywords (that might be in the description or the actual command). For example, I want to know how to toggle my todos using key bindings. I would want to type "Toggle TODO" and expect to get the correct keybinding for it. What you are saying seems to me like something that shows a list of commands based on my first input. I wouldn't know where to start for "Toggle TODO". Get me?

Comment: In that case maybe the answer by @Drew is a little more helpful.  Beyond that the only other thing I can think of that is close is <M-x describe-bindings> which is generally mapped to <C-h b>.  Then you can switch to that window <C-x o> and search <C-s> for the bindings available in whatever modes you have set for the given buffer.

Comment: `C-h b' is really good with my initial tests. I will test it out over the next few days and mark as answer if applicable. Some commands have no key binding set in the beginning, right? Then it becomes a problem. Can you still please update your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in command that more or less does what you want called `apropos-documentation`, bound by default to `C-h d`.  Here's its documentation:

```
(apropos-documentation PATTERN &optional DO-ALL)

Show symbols whose documentation contains matches for PATTERN.
PATTERN can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.

Note that by default this command only searches in the file specified by
‘internal-doc-file-name’; i.e., the etc/DOC file.  With C-u prefix,
or if ‘apropos-do-all’ is non-nil, it searches all currently defined
documentation strings.

Returns list of symbols and documentation found.
```

A couple of points here:

- Unless you're explicitly searching for something you know is built in to Emacs, you probably want to call this as `C-u C-h d` or set the variable `apropos-do-all`.  (That is, the `etc/DOC` file referred to above appears to contain the pre-compiled docstrings for all functions defined in Emacs itself.)
- The docs don't say it, but if you use multiple words, those words may appear in any order, but must be on the same line.  When I tried searching for "org indent", for example, I didn't pull up `org-cycle`, in which both words appear but on separate lines.